# Fully Custom Filter in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a gridview where I need to show percentage of one column with some calculation logic.

It is done, I have a numeric value in one column says "Percentage" but in table I have "mark" field only.

Now I want to add a search filter for this "percentage" field but the problem is in my table there is no percentage so when I try to search percentage it checks for marks value only.

How can I search for "percentage" value in gridview filter instead of searching on "mark" field.

https://www.screencast.com/t/IfUezWnJ

Actually I have a value in database column 'battery' like '1256' and after some calculation I show the battery percentage in gridview. but in gridview search filter I would like to search by percentage. But I could not because in table we have no percentage.

Comment: i tried to find about custom filter in yii 2 but could not able to find such thing

Comment: How are you calculating percentage, and what does your table look like?

Comment: show the marks table that you have add the sample data from the table. we have no idea what you mean by **marks**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculatedrelated-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0).

The main steps are:

1. In the base model create a virtual property (getter method) that do the calculus needed to get the percentage from real mark field: `getPercentage()`
2. In the search model, add a public property (attribute) with the same name of virtual property in the base model (`public $percentage`)
3. In the rules method, add a safe validator for this new property.
4. In the search method, add the proper where clause into the query. This can by a bit tricky if the percent calc is complex or involves subqueries. A simple case would be if the percentage is obtained from another field, let's say `max_value`. 
   In this case you can use a line like: `$query->andWhere ('ilike','mark',$this->percentage/100*max_value)` (Is only a example. Surely `ilike` is not the best operator for this condition.)
5. Use the virtual field in the gridview widget.

If you need a subquery or with statement to get the percentage, you'll need add some additional sentences into $query object, but the main steps are the same.

If you want add sorting capabilities into gridview widget you must define how to order and use expressions if necessary. Tale a look to [this link](https://gist.github.com/XAKEPEHOK/9dfd72d1beb55ddacdcbac6bb61599df)